# Getting Custom Properties value in Test Report from Project Level Tear Down Script

Tags: groovy, soapui

I have used the below code for **Test Report Generation** at Project Level **Tear Down Script** in SOAP UI Open Source version. I want to modify the report by adding Project level "Custom Properties" value to be displayed in the Report. I have tried but not able to get the Custom Properties in the report.

It will be very helpful if somebody could resolve this.

```
/**
*
* Below is the TearDown script for SoapUI Project level
* Which create a custom report in a  given file
* Modify the variable "reportFileName" below
*
**/
 //Modify the file as needed for report file
//def reportFileName = '/tmp/abctestreport.txt'
//Adding the below as user wants specific directory
//Get the project path

def dataFolder =  new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context).projectPath

//Create today's date for storing response
def today = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd")

def filePrefix = "${dataFolder}/TestReports/Automation${today}" as String

def fileNamePart = new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH.mm.ss")

//creating filename dynamically.
def reportFileName = "${filePrefix}/Automation_TestReport_${fileNamePart}.txt" as String


//NOTE: Not required to edit beyond this point

/**
* This class holds the test case details
**/
class TestCaseResultHolder {
def log
Map<String, String> properties = [:]
boolean status

def createProperties(testCase) {
    testCase.getPropertyNames().each { key ->
        properties[key] = testCase.getPropertyValue(key)
    }       
}

def getCaseResult(caseRunner, caseName) {
    log.info "Checking test case status ${caseName}"
    if ( caseRunner.status.toString() == 'FAILED' ){
        log.error "Test case $caseName has failed"
        for ( stepResult in caseRunner?.results ){
            stepResult.messages.each() { msg -> log.info msg }
        }
        return false
    } else {
        log.info "${caseName} is passed"
    }
    true
}

    def buildCaseResult(caseRunner, caseName) {
        status = getCaseResult(caseRunner, caseName)
        if (!status) {
        createProperties(caseRunner.testCase)
        }
    }

}

/**
* This class holds the test suite details
**/
class SuiteResultsHolder {

def log
Map<String, TestCaseResultHolder> casaeResults = [:]
int testCaseCount = 0
int passedCasesCount = 0
int failedCasesCount = 0

def buildSuiteResults(suiteRunner, suiteName){      
    log.info "Building results of test suite ${suiteName}"
    for ( caseRunner in suiteRunner?.results ) {
        def caseName = caseRunner.testCase.name
        testCaseCount++
        def tcHolder = new TestCaseResultHolder(log: log)
        tcHolder.buildCaseResult(caseRunner, caseName)          
        casaeResults[caseName] = tcHolder
        if (tcHolder.status) {
            passedCasesCount++
        } else {
            failedCasesCount++
        }
    }
}

    def getStatus() {
       (0 < failedCasesCount) ? false : true
    }

}

/**
* This class holds the project details
**/
class ProjectResultsHolder {

def log
Map<String, SuiteResultsHolder> suiteResults = [:]
int suiteCount = 0
int passedSuitecount = 0
int failedSuiteCount = 0

def buildProjectResults(projectRunner, projectName) {
    log.info "Building results of test project ${projectName}"          
    for(suiteRunner in projectRunner?.results) {
        def suiteName =  suiteRunner.testSuite.name
        suiteCount++
        def suiteResultsHolder = new SuiteResultsHolder(log: log)
        suiteResultsHolder.buildSuiteResults(suiteRunner, suiteName)
        suiteResults[suiteName] = suiteResultsHolder
        if (suiteResultsHolder.status) {
            passedSuitecount++
        } else {
            failedSuiteCount++
        }
    }
}

    def getStatus() {
        (0 < failedSuiteCount) ? false : true
    }

}

//Get the status string based on boolean
def getResult(status){ status == true ? 'SUCCEED' : 'FAILED'}

 //Draws a line
def drawLine(def letter = '=', def count = 70) { letter.multiply(count)}

//Gets the summary report
def getSummaryReport(project, projectResultHolder) {
    def report = new StringBuffer()
    report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
    report.append("\t\t\tTest Execution Summary\n")
    report.append(drawLine('-', 60)).append('\n')
    report.append("Project : ${project.name}\n")
    report.append("Result : ${getResult(projectResultHolder.status)}\n")
    report.append("Total test suites executed: ${projectResultHolder.suiteCount}\n")
    report.append("Test suites passed: ${projectResultHolder.passedSuitecount}\n")
    report.append("Test suites failed: ${projectResultHolder.failedSuiteCount}\n")
    report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
    report
}

//Gets the test case report
def getTestCaseReport(testCaseReport) {
    def report = new StringBuffer()
    report.append(drawLine('-', 60)).append('\n')
    report.append("\t\tTest Case Details:\n")
    report.append(drawLine('-', 60)).append('\n')
      testCaseReport.each { kase, tcReport ->
      report.append("Name : ${kase}\n")
      report.append("Status : ${getResult(tcReport.status)}\n")
        if (!tcReport.status) {
            report.append("Properties : ${tcReport.properties.toString()}\n")
        }
    }
    report
}

//Get the detailed report
def getDetailedReport(projectResultHolder) {
def report = new StringBuffer()
report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
report.append("\t\t\tTest Execution Detailed Report\n")
report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
projectResultHolder.suiteResults.each { suite, details ->
    report.append("Test Suite : ${suite}\n")
    report.append("Result : ${getResult(details.status)}\n")
    report.append("Total Cases : ${details.testCaseCount}\n")
    report.append("Cases Passed : ${details.passedCasesCount}\n")
    report.append("Cases Failed: ${details.failedCasesCount}\n")
    report.append(getTestCaseReport(details.casaeResults))
    report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
    report.append(drawLine()).append('\n')
    }
    report
}

//Save the contents to a file
def saveToFile(file, content) {
    if (!file.parentFile.exists()) {
        file.parentFile.mkdirs()
        log.info "Directory did not exist, created"
    }
    file.write(content) 
    assert file.exists(), "${file.name} not created"
}

def holder = new ProjectResultsHolder(log: log)
holder.buildProjectResults(runner, project.name)

def finalReport = new StringBuffer()
finalReport.append(getSummaryReport(project, holder))
finalReport.append(getDetailedReport(holder))

def reportFile = new File(reportFileName)
saveToFile(reportFile, finalReport.toString())
```

Answer (score 0):

below is the code snippet you can use. Screenshot shows I have used this script in project teardown script.
Integrate the below code, add/append to StringBuffer "finalReport.append()" Content as per your requirement.

```
    List<String> plist = project.getPropertyNames()
    plist.each{it -> log.info "key = "+ it.toString() 
//finalReport.append("key = "+ it.toString())
    log.info "Value ="+project.getPropertyValue(it.toString())}
```

[image]

accept the solution if it works for you , it will also help others

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is working fine in tear down script and I am getting the response in logs but in the report generation, it is not working. Can you please have a look at the report code mentioned in the post and help in appending this code snippet in the report.

Comment: Sorry , don't have time for that.. please try on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The post is very old, but if someone is searching a solution, after tryng different ways, the following code finally works for me:

```
    def createProperties(testCase) {
        // 'Properties' must match your step properties-box name you assigned, 
        // by the way default value is just 'Properties'
        if (testCase.testSteps["Properties"]){
            testCase.testSteps["Properties"].getPropertyNames().each { key ->
                properties[key] = testCase.testSteps["Properties"].getPropertyValue(key)
                log.info "Created properties ${key} = " + properties[key]
            }       
        }     
    }
```